# How do I resolve a kernel panic without reinstalling?

Tags: kernel

I forgot to make a backup and it would take forever to reinstall and get it to a point I could use even if I were to copy over the home folder. I recently got a kernel panic with the message 'attempted to kill init' a couple seconds after displaying the kubuntu load screen. I have an installation on another disk that I can copy over system files from, but I'm in the dark as to what I should copy over.

Here is a picture:

[image: kernel pani - not syncing: Attempted to kill Init!]

Comment: What did you do before you started getting the kernel panic? Have you tried booting a different kernel version?

Comment: I installed three or four desktop environments, mate, gnome flashback and some other one emulating mac osx

Comment: Oh, and I ran an apt get upgrade

Comment: sorry I can't narrow it down much more than that. One moment, I'll reboot and take a picture of the issue

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxwYn8K9RD7ZdHg0LTdJdEpxV3c/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Try holding down 'Shift' before the computer boots, and selecting another kernel in the 'Advanced options for Ubuntu' menu in GRUB, or recovery mode.

Comment: I have tried booting in all three kernels that are there, .24 .30 and .32 and I've tried booting into the recovery mode of each as well, it seems to be something else

Comment: hmmm... are you able to inspect the hdd(is it a hdd?)e.g. by using a boot-stick?you could try to substitute the kernel by removing his files(this would be the last chance!)

Comment: I've tried copying the kernel files over from my other installation and it makes no difference, it seems to load the kernel fine but some module it catching it

Comment: ok, the problem should be a start/stop-script of a module. We'll have to know wich one.

Comment: how would I find it? I have a fully functional installation elsewhere on the same hard drive and can access the partition, but where are they located and where would I start?

Comment: do you know how to start a chat?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16138/discussion-between-sbergeron-and-littlebyblue).

Comment: Now it gives me not syncing: VFS: unable to mount root fake on unknown block (0,0)

Comment: ok, things getting clear. the Problem should be  now in the startscript _S10checkroot.sh_ you should be able to find it under _/etc/rcS.d/S10checkroot.sh_  at first try to substitute it with the old _S10checkroot.sh_.

Comment: Did you run `$ sudo apt get update` before running `$ sudo apt-get upgrade`? because If you are using different Kernels, maybe apt wasn't able to upgrade  satisfactorily, and something went wrong.